# How do I update a Sprite's lineTo() in an enter_frame function in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, sprite, updates

Basically, what I want is for a sprite to fill an area that's constantly being updated. I have created two lines that always point in the opposite direction of the cursor, and what I want is to create a sprite with corners in these two lines' start and endpoints. This is what I do to initially create the sprite:

```
function addWalls():void {
    var w:Sprite = new Sprite();
    w.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
    //sArray is an array containing the two lines, and the lines' length == 200
    w.graphics.moveTo(sArray[0].x, sArray[0].y);
    w.graphics.lineTo(sArray[1].x, sArray[1].y);
    w.graphics.lineTo(sArray[1].x + Math.cos(sArray[1].rotation / 180 * Math.PI) * 200, sArray[1].y + Math.sin(sArray[1].rotation / 180 * Math.PI) * 200);
    w.graphics.lineTo(sArray[0].x + Math.cos(sArray[0].rotation / 180 * Math.PI) * 200, sArray[0].y + Math.sin(sArray[0].rotation / 180 * Math.PI) * 200);
    w.graphics.lineTo(sArray[0].x, sArray[0].y);
    w.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(w);
    wArray[0] = w;
}
```

How am I supposed to update this code in an enter_frame function for it to change according to the lines?

Comment: I'm not certain I know what your having trouble with. My best guess, is you're just needing to do  `w.graphics.clear()` (followed by your drawing logic) in your enter frame handler.  Or is it the drawing logic you're having an issue with?

Comment: That did wonders, thanks :)

Comment: Great! Added it as an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would be to move your drawing logic to it's own method.  Then just call the `graphics.clear()` method in your enterFrame handler:

```
function addWalls():void {
    var w:Sprite = new Sprite();
    drawWalls();
    addChild(w);
    wArray[0] = w;
}

function drawWalls(w:Sprite):void {
    w.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
    //sArray is an array containing the two lines, and the lines' length == 200
    w.graphics.moveTo(sArray[0].x, sArray[0].y);
    w.graphics.lineTo(sArray[1].x, sArray[1].y);
    w.graphics.lineTo(sArray[1].x + Math.cos(sArray[1].rotation / 180 * Math.PI) * 200, sArray[1].y + Math.sin(sArray[1].rotation / 180 * Math.PI) * 200);
    w.graphics.lineTo(sArray[0].x + Math.cos(sArray[0].rotation / 180 * Math.PI) * 200, sArray[0].y + Math.sin(sArray[0].rotation / 180 * Math.PI) * 200);
    w.graphics.lineTo(sArray[0].x, sArray[0].y);
    w.graphics.endFill();
}

function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void {
    for(var i:int=0;i<wArray.length;i++){
        wArray[i].graphics.clear(); //clear the current graphics;
        drawWalls(wArray[i]);
    }
}

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
```